# About AV mode in Canon DSLR

Tags: canon, canon-5d-mark-ii

I have Canon 5d mk ii and I use Canon 28mm 1.8 lens. I like the camera and lens. Usually I shoot with f2 Iso3200 in AV mode. So in dark situations shutter speed slows down to 1/10 or even less. So I would like to know if there is option for AV mode, to not allow camera shutter speed to be lower than 1/15 or 1/25? Thanks

I know there  is also posibility so use TV mode, But I prefer AV mode for many situations for getting more natural colours and light in my pictures.

Comment: If you're fixing aperture and ISO and not letting shutter speed vary appropriately, how do you expect to get a properly exposed shot?

Comment: [When to use shutter priority instead of aperture priority?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6161/when-to-use-shutter-priority-instead-of-aperture-priority)

Comment: What do you want the behaviour to be when there isn't enough light to get a shot at f/2 with ISO 3200 at (say) 1/15 second? Do you want the camera to not let you fire, or adjust one of the other settings for you?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you think you get more natural colours in Av mode. Back in the film days, people would underexpose for that purpose, but as long as you don't overexpose, colours will be fine. If you have a preference for shutter speed, then Tv mode is just for you. If you want to get underexposed pictures (for whatever reason), then there is exposure compensation to achieve that.

Comment: Or use manual mode with auto ISO. The only problem there is that you then lose the ability to do exposure compensation on most Canon SLRs.

Comment: Manual mode may actually work best for the OP, also if lighting conditions don't change much between shots, but bright light sources moving into/out of the frame may confuse the light meter.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this isn't available on the 5D Mark ii, atleast not without third party hacks. It is a feature they made available on the mark iii with an option in the settings to limit the minimum automatic shutter speed as well as the minimum and maximum automatic ISO settings.

I heard some mention that it might be possible with Magic Lantern, but it isn't possible with just the stock Mark ii.

Comment: I don't believe the Mk II has this (read: I can't find it on mine)

Comment: @RowlandShaw - yeah, after reactivating my CS6 and getting in to the manual, I can confirm it isn't there.